# Typo3 Typoscript additionalHeaders header location using variable

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I try to redirect a link which is coming, but before part of the link should be replaced.

```
tmp.getSlug = TEXT
tmp.getSlug.data = getIndpEnv : TYPO3_REQUEST_URL
tmp.getSlug.replacement {
    10 {
        search = myLinkPart
        replace = myNewLinkPart
    }
}
     
    
config.additionalHeaders.10 {
    header = Location: {tmp.getSlug}
}
```

So from: [www.myUrl.de/test/myLinkPart/test2/](http://www.myUrl.de/test/myLinkPart/test2/)
To: [www.myUrl.de/test/myNewLinkPart/test2/](http://www.myUrl.de/test/myNewLinkPart/test2/)

It must be inside Typoscript because of other conditions.

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: In general it's not possible to use "tmp" and other TypoScript objects in stdWrap context. `Location: {tmp.getSlug}` won't be filled. Use fully stdWrap functionality instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i dont know in which way I can use it in my example. Could you please help me?

Comment: Since additionalHeaders is just an array of numeric keys, there is nothing like stdWrap available there anyway, so IMHO this task can not be solved.

See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#additionalheaders

It seems that you actually want a redirect, do you?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to redirect in .htaccess with a RewriteRule?

Comment: In case of some conditions regarding FE-Login, unfortunately it must be inside Typoscript..

Comment: What TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Typo3 10

Comment: have you considered migrating all the redirecting code and conditions to Middlewares??

Comment: Are there any more ideas?

Answer (score -1):

you are mixing different objects in a non functional way.

First you define `tmp.getSlug` as a typoscript object. Then you try to use it as a data variable.
Additional everything beyond `tmp.` is not available at rendering time. (it just is available when the typoscript is scanned.)

If you want to use the evaluation of `tmp.getSlug` you need to assign it to a permanent object and then store it in a register so you can access it afterwards.

Additional you need a flexible object to compose the `Location` header, which by default just contains a string.
Either a text object where you can use data (which must be evaluated and stored in a register before) or a `COA` to compose the static and the dynamic string.

This might be a solution:

```
tmp.getSlug = TEXT
tmp.getSlug.data = getIndpEnv : TYPO3_REQUEST_URL
tmp.getSlug.replacement {
    10 {
        search = myLinkPart
        replace = myNewLinkPart
    }
}

config.additionalHeaders.10 {
    header.cObject = COA
    header.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = Location: 

        20 < tmp.getSlug
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your example, but it doesn`t seem to work. No redirect is called? Any other ideas? Would help me a lot. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: can you find the output in your pages? maybe you start and assign the value to any fluid-variable you can inspekt in frontend.

Comment: The replacement works, if I implement it as "page.9999 < tmp.getSlug" content, it appears, but the redirect does nothing.

Comment: does the redirect appear in the html? syntactical correct?

Comment: No, nothing happens regarding a redirect

Comment: does any redirect meta tag appear in the server-response? could you insert any redirect (either a static or your dynamic url)?

Comment: If I use a static url its the same, nothing happens. I think, that the redirect doesnt work in this case.

Comment: No more ideas? It would be very helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not working since TYPO3 v9: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Breaking-86492-RemovedStdWrapSupportForConfigadditionalHeaders.html